# How to get the cmd window's height (in lines)?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

I want to do a personalized "more" command where the lines are output page by page. 
Therefore, I need to get the height of the windows in a variable, in an unit of lines.
Is there a way to do that simply in a batch file?

Else, how could I use the more command (or a similar one), but with a header to see a kind of title bar at each page echoed?

Comment: The Windows command interpreter is **not** DOS.

Comment: @IInspectable So DOS is like an OS, but the CMD is a window faking this OS ?

Comment: The Windows command interpreter language is compatible with the language used by the DOS command interpreter. You cannot run DOS executables in or from the Windows command prompt. The Windows command prompt is Windows. No faking.

Comment: You have this question marked with [tag:powershell], are you wanting the window height in powershell or the command prompt? The answers are *very* different. You seem to be running a batch script, could your process be re-written to a powershell script? It is much easier to do stuff like this inside powershell.

Comment: I've only heard about powershell being an extension to CMD or something like that, and it was able to find the height of the console. So I put it in the tags to know if it is possible to use it...

Comment: PowerShell is **not** an extension to CMD. CMD is a shell that vaguely resembles DOS and is compatible with most commands you might have used there 20 years ago (seriously, DOS was killed a dozen years ago), PowerShell is a completely independent shell built on .NET.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you tagged your question with PowerShell, this is the PowerShell script you would use to get the PowerShell console height in lines:

```
C:\PS> $host.UI.RawUI.WindowSize.Height
50
```

To save that to a variable in a BAT file do this:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %A in ('powershell.exe -noprofile -command $host.ui.rawui.WindowSize.Height') do SET result=%A
echo %result%
```

Comment: How can I use this in the .bat file as a variable? What to write in it?

Comment: If you are on a system with PowerShell installed, just shell out `powershell.exe -command $host.UI.RawUI.WindowSize.Height`

Comment: If I write what you wrote, It gives me the right result, but it doesn't store it in a variable. I tried to write on a line `SET /p numLines=powershell.exe -command $host.UI.RawUI.WindowSize.Height` but it does not store the number of lines, but the command as a string. I feel we are near the answer.

Comment: @Che If your question has been answered you should mark the appropriate answer as "the" answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that with pure Batch commands, you need an .exe program. For example, you may use my Window.exe program this way:

```
Window.exe size
set /A "lines=%errorlevel%>>16"
```

You may get Window.exe program from [this post](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3428&p=17216#p17216)

By the while, Windows.exe file is 3072 bytes long, whereas powershell.exe is more than 450000 bytes long and run *much slower* in order to get the same result of this case!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you can get the maximum amount of lines in the entire console with:

```
mode con: /status | more +3 > stat.txt
set /p lines=<stat.txt
del stat.txt
```

To change the max lines do:

```
mode con cols=80 lines=[number of lines]
```

ANd you can limit how many lines the consol has, that is the maximum amount of lines. If they change the console size to something smaller, a scroll bar will allow them to move.

Other then that I don't know of any way to do what you want.

Mona

Comment: If I echo %lines% it shows : `Printer output is not being rerouted.`

Comment: It outputs me 300, I see about 25 lines on my screen on windowed mode. I think this is like number of lines that can be scrolled in the command window before they get deleted. What I need is the number of lines that can be shown on screen without being hidden and requiring a scroll. I think it's possible, because the "more" command itself can know this height to show things properly on screen.

Comment: If you set the console lines limit to 25 or less, and unless they intentionally changed it to a smaller size, it will stay that size. I can do this in C#, but that will require you to use an exe as a command.

Comment: The problem with this is that I need to do it only in the batch file, and the number of lines is not fixed... The console could use only 10 lines, or be bigger on all the screen's height.

Comment: Exactly, the more command is an exe. That is why it can access the screen hieght. You can't do this in batch without using an operable program for some in a wierd fashion.

Answer (score 0):

For a one simple line:

```bat
for /f tokens^=2 %%L in ('mode con^|find "Lin"')do set _lines=%%~L"
```